# Conversion from varchar to datetime for sorting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have column with varchar datatype . which contains date as below format:

```
04-JAN-18 11.23.32.195734 AM +05:30
```

I need to sort rows based on latest timestamp.What is the function to use?

```
SELECT *
FROM ent_organizations
order by TO_TIMESTAMP(updatedtimestamp,'YYYY-MON-DD HH.MI.SS.FF') desc
```

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input
>   string
>   01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Why do you store date/time values in a varchar column?

Comment: Never store timestamps as `varchar`. Your current problem is one good example why not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to `TIMESTAMP` like this:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(updatedtimestamp,'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM TZH:TZM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')
```

If you use it for sorting then it will be based on UTC times, not local time values.

Comment: thanks its working.What is the best practice for storing date/datetime values in oracle column.

Comment: Do you mean this question seriously??? Check `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP ...` data types: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref117